# Do action-reaction conservative forces come in pairs?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, conservative-field

If $\ \vec{F_{12}}\ $ denotes the force on particle 1 by particle 2 and is conservative, is $\ \vec{F_{21}}\ $conservative too?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct, according to newton's third law, each force has an equal reaction force in opposite direction on another body.

If $\vec F_{12}$ is conservative, then I don't think so that its reaction pair should have other nature (non-conservative). So, $\vec F_{21}$ must be conservative.

For example: $\vec F_{12}=\frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}\hat r$, where $\hat r$ is unit vector in direction of position vector $\vec r_{1,2}$. similarly, $\vec F_{21}=-\frac{Gm_2m_1}{r^2} \hat r$, which constitutes the action-reaction pair. Both are conservative.

Comment: But how can one prove this in general?

Comment: @Curious Maybe think about what you're really asking for here when you say "prove". The math and theory must match what we observe and they are formulated to match what we observe, not the other way around. Ultimately it comes down to making the theory and math match accurately describe what we observe.

Answer (score 0):

You can find mathematical proofs I suppose (if one force is equal to the gradient of a potential, the other will also be the gradient of the same potential with minus sign). But it is better to understand that the two forces are quantities associated with a unique interaction between two objects. It does not even make sens to ask if the two forces can have different characters. The two forces describing the interaction are always of the same type as they describe the same thing. If you think that you found a Newton's 3 law pair of forces that have different natures then you make one of the beginers' errors in analysing a system. I am not saying that you do, but it is a common mistake to associate gravity with normal force, for eaxample, as third law pairs in the work of students in introductory physics. And the error comes from failing to realize that the two forces are the two sides of the same interaction.